# Sentence to Word Table with R

Tags: r, data-mining, text-mining, cpu-word, sentencecase

I have some sentences, from the sentences I want to separate the words to get row vector each. But the words are repeating to match with the largest sentence's row vector that I do not want. I want no matter how large the sentence is, the row vector of each of the sentences will only be the words one time.

```
sentence <- c("case sweden", "meeting minutes ht board meeting st march now also attachment added agenda today s board meeting", "draft meeting minutes board meeting final meeting minutes ht board meeting rd april")
sentence <- cbind(sentence)
word_table <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(sentence), " "))
test <- cbind(sentence, word_table)
```

This is what I get now, [image]

And this is what I want, 
[image]

I mean **no-repeating**.

Comment: Dataframes work as data structures with the same number of entries per row, a list based structure might be more efficient?

Comment: Yeah, either a list structure or a "long" dataframe, with string ID in one col and words in the second col.

Comment: For example, for the third sentence what is largest, `read.table` is creating one extra row, in total now for three sentence it is becoming 4 rows, what is not expected :(

Comment: Aha, I see. Yes, it is working now. thanks @rawr

Comment: Thank you very much guys, stackoverflow is really wonderful, discussing with you all really solved my problem in the shortest time span. :)

Comment: Please post as answer, it is working wonderfully on big data set as well, I just tested.

Comment: Okay, I am posting, but if you post as ans, would not it give you extra point, because I am new in stack, and I can not see an option to take your answer as the answer.

Comment: Sorry, this way it is not working although there is no extra white space or tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution from **rawr**,

```
sentence <- c("case sweden", "meeting minutes ht board meeting st march now also attachment added agenda today s board meeting", "draft meeting minutes board meeting final meeting minutes ht board meeting rd april")
dd <- read.table(text = paste(sentence, collapse = '\n'), fill = TRUE)
test <- cbind(sentence, dd)
```

### Or,

```
cc <- read.table(text = paste(gsub('\n', '', sentence), collapse = '\n'), fill = TRUE)
test1 <- cbind(sentence, cc)
```

Thanks.